# read a file and sort marks

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a code to read a file of names, emails and marks in order to sort data from the lower mark to higher 
The structure of file is  name;email;mark
                          name;email;mark
                          ...
The problem is that I get error with this line 'note.get(j+1)=note.get(j)'
"unexpected type required variable found value"

here is my code is it correct ?? help please

```
   try {
 BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new 
 FileReader("C://wamp/www/text.txt"));
 String lineText = null;
 ArrayList<String> nom = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> email= new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<Double> note = new ArrayList<Double>();
 while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
 String[] split = lineText.split(";");
 nom.add(split[0]); 
 email.add(split[1]);
 note.add(Double.parseDouble(split[2])); 
}
double temp;
String temps;
 for(int i=0;i<note.size();i++){
for(int j=0;j<note.size()-1-i;j++){
  if(note.get(j)> note.get(j+1)){
    temp=note.get(j);
    note.get(j+1)=note.get(i);
    note.get(i)=temp;
      temps=nom.get(j);
    nom.get(j+1)=nom.get(i);
    nom.get(i)=temps;
            temps=email.get(j);
    email.get(j+1)=email.get(i);
    email.get(i)=temps;
  }
  }    

   }

  lineReader.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
  System.err.println(ex);
  }
  }
```

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: You can not assign a value to the result of a getter method. Change `note.get(j+1)=note.get(i);` to `note.set(j+1,note.get(i));` and so on

Comment: Wrap your data in a `StudentMark` class with a `name`, `email` and `note` field. Have it implement the `Comparable` interface. Read all lines in your file, and create a new `StudentMark` object with the data you read per line. Add that to a list. Use `Collections#sort` to sort your array.

Comment: @Jens thanks for ur answer ur right  I know my mistake now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to sort your list.  First off, create a new class so you can link nom, email, and note all together:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable {

    String nom;
    String email;
    double note;

    public Entry(String nom, String email, Double note) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.email = email;
        this.note = note;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if(!(o instanceof Entry)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong type!");

        Entry other = ((Entry) o);

        if(this.note > other.note) return 1;
        if(this.note == other.note) return 0;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You can implement the Comparable interface so you can easily sort using built-in java methods however you want.  [Read more about this here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Do this before you read the file:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
```

And each line/entry you read (probably want to add input validation):

```
Entry next = new Entry(split[0], split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[3]));
entries.add(next);
```

Then, when you're done reading/creating your list of entries, simply do this to sort it:

```
Collections.sort(entries);
```

Your list will now be sorted from highest->lowest. Reverse it:

```
Collections.sort(entries, Collections.<Entry>reverseOrder());
```

Comment: @Perston Garno thank you for ur answer my code works fine now but ur method is more organized I will try it :)

Comment: @maevabell no problem.  Rule of thumb, never reinvent the wheel because there's most likely an easy solution built into the language standard library:) But it's a good way to learn though regardless! (mostly referring to java)